# What type of lens is this?

Tags: geometric-optics, lenses

My teacher taught me that there are two families of lenses - convex family (the lenses which are thicker at the centre and thinner at the apices) and concave family (the lenses which are thinner at the centre and thicker at the apices). Below I have given an image of a lens in which the radii of curvature ($R$) of both the surfaces are equal. What type of lens is this? There is no 'thickness' difference between the centre and apices. The thickness is same at the centre and the apices. So, what lens is this? It does not satisfy the definitions of both convex family and concave family. Please explain what lens is this. I am confused.[image: Image of the lens]

Answer (score 2):

It's called *meniscus*.  A lens with one convex and one concave side is convex-concave or meniscus. You can find more about them [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens).

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer is you cannot answer that question without knowing the medium outside the lens , but generally speaking the medium is considered to be air which is optically rarer than material of lens which is generally glass .

Some terminology you should be aware of before coming to answer : Concave =  side of the lens which   bulge towards denser medium and convex side of the lens  bulge towards rarer medium.

Now , assuming if light rays are coming from left : Side 1 = Concave  and Side 2 = Convex, hence the lens is  concavo-convex lens.